# Move files with all subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to move all files and directories to another specific directory.

```
|
\---MainDirectory
    |   MainFiles
    |
    +---Subdirectory1
    |       MultipleFiles1
    |
    \---Subdirectory2
            MultipleFiles2
```

```
|
\---TargetDirectory
    |   MainFiles
    |
    +---Subdirectory1
    |       MultipleFiles1
    |
    \---Subdirectory2
            MultipleFiles2
```

Currently using following code with batch file:

```bash
move "MainDirectory" "TargetDirectory"
```

It is moving only MainDirectory like:

```
|
\---TargetDirectory
        MainFiles
```

I do not want to move MainDirectory. I know it is very basic question, but I am not expert and have searched for more than 2 hours and haven't found a solution.

I tried

```bash
robocopy "MainDirectory" "TargetDirectory" /MOVE
```

It is also moving only MainFiles.
[image]

This code is moving successfully but removing MainDirectory which I do not want to remove

```bash
robocopy.exe "MainDirectory" "TargetDirectory" /S /Move
```

Comment: Please take a look at the output from `robocopy /?`, `[ENTER]`ed in a Command Prompt window. Pay special attention to the options explaining how to move files and directories, as opposed to just copying them.

Comment: I tried it is also not working, robocopy "C:\Users\cz 3\Desktop\Command\Downloading\" "C:\Users\cz 3\Desktop\Command\Files\" /e
Error: The filename, directory name, or volue label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: You obviously never read it, because you have not included any options for moving either files or directories. Please try harder, we are not here to write code, based solely upon your inability to read and follow the basic usage information for a single command. I will say however, because it is not clear from the usage information, that directories should not end with trailing backward slashes.

Comment: After reading your scolding I tried many thing but still the same issue that only main files are copying with this code "robocopy "C:\Users\cz 3\Desktop\Command\Downloading" "C:\Users\cz 3\Desktop\Command\Files" /MOVE  /R:100 "

Comment: What was the output when you ran that? Please put that code, and your output from running it, into your question body itself, not in the comment section. There is an [Edit] link below your question for you to do that.

Comment: What happened your subdirectory option(s)? Without any, you should expect only files to be actioned.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't found a better way than this

```
robocopy /e /move "MainDirectory" "TargetDirectory" & md "MainDirectory"
```